# How to limit Plain text content control in MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, forms

I want to create one Form using Developer tab in MS word 2013.

When I write anything in `Plain text content control`, it will expand like below Image.

[image]

I want to give width limit so that control can not be expanded.

> How can give limit to Plain text content control?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the plain text control does not support width limitation. At least, I've fount nothing among VBA properties.

I would suggest to use an alternative control, the ActiveX-textbox. In properties, set:

```
AutoSize = true
MaxLength = N (in characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert content control inside an invisible table. That will allow you to define width of a cell, and in turn, width of your content control.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can control the column width and row height to limit how much text will be *shown* but this will not limit how much text is actually in the control. If the user is going to print the form, this will be sufficient. If it's going to be processed electronically, then it may matter.